# Retrieve/Preserve the file - if there is an exception caught by catch block when using "try.. catch" with onexception in Apache Camel

Tags: apache-camel

In below route , i am using both "try..catch" and onexception features .
If there is any exception in my bean or the lines outside try block..file is moved to ".error" since i used `moveFailed` option but during exception which are caught by catch block generated by lines of try block,file is lost..

```
    1.when server is down
    2.when connection timeout
```

Please suggest the ways to preserve the file during such failures/exceptions

```
<camelContext streamCache="false" useMDCLogging="true" id="XXX" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <streamCaching spoolDirectory="/tmp/cachedir/#camelId#/#uuid#" spoolUsedHeapMemoryThreshold="70" bufferSize="65536" anySpoolRules="true" id="myCacheConfig"/>
    <onException >
        <description>An exception was encountered.</description>
        <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
        <log message="somemessage" loggingLevel="INFO"/>
    </onException>   
<route >        
    <from uri="file:D:/Users/Desktop/src?moveFailed=.error" />
    <transform>
        <method ref="somebean" method="somemethod"/>
    </transform>
    <doTry>  
        <to uri="file:D:/Users/Desktop/src" /> 
         <log message="transfered successfully" />           
         <doCatch>
            <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
                <log message="Exception occurred and Stopping the Route"/>
                <to uri="controlbus:route?routeId=XXXX&amp;action=stop"/>                       
               <log message="Stopped the Route:XXX"/>
        </doCatch>
    </doTry> 
</route>
```

Please suggest the ways to preserve the file during such failures/exceptions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rethrow the exception in your docatch-block to reach the onException block.

```
     <doCatch>
        <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
            <log message="Exception occurred and Stopping the Route"/>
            <to uri="controlbus:route?routeId=XXXX&amp;action=stop&amp;async=true"/> // async=true to resume/finish this route                       
           <log message="Stopped the Route:XXX"/>
           <throwException  exception="java.lang.Exception"/> // dont know the exact syntax in xml dsl
    </doCatch>
```

Comment: if we re-throw the exception , when should i  stop the route .
please consider my scenario to stop route in catch. Also provide prototype/structure for the same

Comment: You can use the async parameter of the controlbus. When stopping a route with an inflight exchange camel automatically uses the graceful shutdown feature and waits(default 300 sec) before it "kills" the route.